# How do I generate an ephemeral TLS key and certificate in Android (without KeyStore)

Tags: android, ssl

How do I create an ephemeral private key and certificate (like WebRTC does for DTLS) for use with [`SSLServerSocket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/javax/net/ssl/SSLServerSocket) / [`SSLSocket`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket).

It should not be in [KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore) and private key bytes should be accessible by the code (to be serialized/deserialized over another secure connection).

Comment: Why? Nobody will trust it.

Comment: @user207421, It is part of an automatic process, ans is not related to serving HTTPS pages.

Comment: Sure, nobody will trust the ephemeral keys. But therefore it's combined with authentication mechanisms as ECDSA or PSK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a look at

[Eclipse/Californium - ECDHE cryptography](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/blob/master/scandium-core/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/scandium/dtls/cipher/ECDHECryptography.java)

And just to mention:
ECDHE is not about providing authentication, it's about providing [Perfect Forward  Secrecy](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Forward_Secrecy). Therefore two random and ephemeral key-pairs are used to encrypt the key-exchange in the handshake in a way, that after destroying these ephemeral keys, could not be decrypted. Even, if the long term credentials as the private key of your x.509 certificate, could be accessed. 
It's usually used together with mechanisms as ECDSA or PSK to ensure the authentication additionally.

```
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.spec.ECGenParameterSpec;

try {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256r1"));
    KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
} catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I already found out that TLS-PSK is what I need. With PSK I just don't need those certificates. And it is supported by `conscrypt-android` (although deprecated).